# Transition from Digital Ocean to Azure - Parse Server

Tags: azure, migration, digital-ocean, parse-server

I have a Parse Server on a Digital Ocean droplet and an iOS & android app, that uses the Parse Server!

Now, I'm offered a free license for Azure, so questions have arisen! Keep in mind that the current monthly cost of the droplet is $25. It may seem cheap, but we are a startup so money are not flying around!

Q1: Is Azure a good solution for a medium-traffic photo-sharing app? (~ 1k monthly users)

Q2: What are the necessary steps? I guess that the new server should point to our domain and the previous should stop! Also, I believe that a copy of our DB should be uploaded to the new server... is there anything else I'm unaware of?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to edit this with specific technical questions, stack overflow isn't a really place for Q1. But I have used Azure for many startups ranging from various sizes. I would recommend looking into Microsoft's BizSpark program for helping you get even free hosting for azure for a startup if your startup qualifies.

Comment: instead of saying monthly 1000 users, perhaps a more relevant question would be the amount of bandwidth you are consuming.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, your question is off-topic, as it's opinion-soliciting ("*is Azure a good solution for... *") and too broad ("*what are the necessary steps...*").  Without specific details for your question, there's really no way to answer this.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you will edit the question to become more specific. Meanwhile, here is all you need to do get your parse over to Azure

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-publication-of-parse-server-with-azure-managed-services/